# Checking if $(2^p+1)/3$ is prime with multiplicative order and recurrence relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations, primality-test

Here is what I observed :

Let $(2^p+1)/3$ be a Wagstaff number $W_n$.

Let the sequence $a_n = ord({a_{n-1}},\frac{2^{p}+1}{3}), a_0 = 2p$, where $p$ is a prime number.

Then $W_n$ is prime if the number $2$ is reached after some iterations.

For example :

With $W_{11}$ we get $2p = 22$, $(2^{11}+1)/3 = 683$

- $ord(22, 683) = 341$
- $ord(341, 683) = 11$
- $ord(11, 683) = 682$
- $ord(682, 683) = 2$

We got the sequence $22  \rightarrow 341 \rightarrow 11 \rightarrow 682 \rightarrow 2$, we reached $2$ so $683$ is prime.

Another example :

With $W_{29}$ we get $2p = 58$, $(2^{29}+1)/3 = 178956971$

We got the sequence $58  \rightarrow 1516584 \rightarrow 29 \rightarrow 1516584 \rightarrow 29$ etc., We don't reached $2$ so $178956971$ is not prime.

For the moment, I didn't find a counterexample.

I need help for proving it if it's true but I don't know how to start. If you found a counterexample please tell me.

Comment: Determining the order for large composites is extremely difficult. So, this test would have very little practical use.